# What does colon ':' in API request mean?

Tags: javascript, axios

i am using firebase for my project ,the documentation gives me the endpoint for signing in users as:

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]
```

i want to know what does the colon `:` mean, for example the word key after the question mark shows its a parameter likewise what does the notion `accounts:signInWithPassword` mean.The reason:I have an axios instance with config:

```
axios.create(
  {
    baseURL:"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1",
    params:{
    apiKey:"somekey"
    }
  })
```

now since the baseUrl shown above remains same for firebase signing in with email and password or signing up with email and password. I want to dynamically embed  `accounts:signInWithPassword` and `accounts:signUp` for respective requests and i am not sure if specifying `accounts:respectiveUsecase` in params object would work.

Comment: That's a regular colon, not a semicolon

Comment: @CertainPerformance aand what does that mean ?

Comment: Nothing per se. It's a naming convention specific to that API.

Comment: It's just part of the text. Nothing particularly significant to it - it could have been `accounts-signInWithPassword` or `accounts_signInWithPassword` and it'd work the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A colon doesn't have any special meaning in an URL path.  It's just a convention those APIs tend to use in their paths.

There are a handful of metacharacters that do:

- question marks (?) and hashes (#) delimit the query or search parts
- `%` is used for escaping characters (e.g. `%0A`)
- `+` is sometimes an encoding for a space instead of `%20`.
- `&` generally separates query parameters (e.g. `foo=bar&baz`), though this is not a part of the standard. Some server software could expect e.g. semicolon-separated parameters.

As @deceze pointed out, colons do have a special meaning in the host part, e.g. `https://user:pass@host/path:where:colons:do:not:matter`.

Comment: `:` does have a meaning when passing username and password in the host field…

Comment: Also, `/` has a meaning in URLs. As does `+` (substitutes spaces), `%` (used for character encoding sequences) and more. So, it's not *just* `?` and `#` that are special. A character in an URL might be interpreted differently, even if it's not part of the URL scheme

Comment: @VLAZ Do slashes really have a semantic meaning? I mean, sure, they tend to be directory separators, but there's nothing that says a web server is backed by a file system...

Comment: They don't *have* to be directories but they *do* denote some sort of path and the slashes are separators there. And you can easily have path parameters, e.g., `/api/{id}` or `api/{action}/{resourceName}` or something. You can also put that as query parameters but depends on how you want to express your API. You *could* do `/api_{action}_{resourceName}` or similar but you'd be working against most tools this way and making your life harder.

Comment: If we're covering all special uses of colon, I feel that the use of colon to designate a port as part of the authority should also be mentioned. This is BEFORE any slash designating the start of the path. So `https://user:pass@my.host.com:9999/path:where:colons:do:not:matter` illustrates all uses of colons in a URL: 1) as a separator between username and password 2) to designate a port number 3) as part of the path where it has no special meaning

Answer (score 3):

It is a dynamic value (like a parameter where you in pass in a value directly)

:nounId: The colon (:) before the word indicates that we don't mean the literal string "nounId" as part of the endpoint, but rather that we are expecting some dynamic data to be inside there. From the above example of /ski/:skiId, one actual endpoint might be something like /ski/1234 (where 1234 is the unique ID number of one of the skis in our database.

source: [https://coursework.vschool.io/rest-api-design/#:~:text=%3AnounId%20%3A%20The%20colon%20(%3A)%20before,data%20to%20be%20inside%20there](https://coursework.vschool.io/rest-api-design/#:%7E:text=%3AnounId%20%3A%20The%20colon%20(%3A)%20before,data%20to%20be%20inside%20there).

Answer (score 3):

As others have said - a colon doesn't mean anything special in the URL.

However - I've just read "API Design Patterns" by JJ Geewax (ex-Google engineer who has worked on Firebase) - in it he describes colons being used to signify custom methods (so anything that doesn't fit in the standard POST/GET/PUT/DELETE methods that are seen in for many REST APIs), exactly as you have described with your `signInWithPassword` method. So it seems to be the Google way of doing things.